# Is there anything to do to increase the speed of the inference engine in F#?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, intellisense, cpu

I mostly don't wait for the results or intellisense because it is too slow.

But sometimes, when I am not sure of a type, I would like it to be here, and it takes very long to have the inference run.

However, my CPU is working around 2% all the time..

=> Is it possible to have visual studio be **more agressive** with my computer's ressources ?

**Update**

- I use Visual Beta 11
- while intellisense does appear immediately after loading a solution, it takes a while when modifying the code (around 20-30 seconds)

Comment: Which VS are you referring to? I have had good experience with F# intellisense in VS 2010 so far.

Comment: After the initial type-checking (when you open the proejct), which takes usually 100% of a single core, the IntelliSense should be immediate. It might be using old data if it didn't have time to update, but it should appear immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The F# VS implementation is not stingy about using resources to give you feedback in the editor.  If any IntelliSense info is out of date, it will happily burn one full core (or a little more) trying to catch back up.  And if any stale information is available in the meantime, it should serve up the stale results.  A wait of tens of seconds is unexpected for any 'warm' solution.

(If this is a relatively new install, you might run `ngen eqi` from a VS command prompt to ensure NGEN has finished after the installation; the F# compiler components are slow unless they have been NGEN'd, and this happens in the background after the VS install.)

If you see IntelliSense this slow, I'd be curious to know more about your solution (number of files, size of files, using type providers?, ...) to identify the problem.

Comment: I think I found the culprit. I use a type provider which uses excel. when I modify my code, a new excel process is created, and is using some amount of CPU.

Comment: everytime a "." is pressed, my type provider will be called. btw it gets called many times (3 I think). So a "." in the editor will launch 3 excels.....

Comment: I don't see the case for refreshing that often the type provider. It could use some additional caching intelligence. is there anyway to program it into the type provider ? like a lazy provider ?

Comment: solved it. it is quite a nightmare for a newbie. memoizing is very touchy as it is easy to have closure, meaning you memoize the invocation, and not the results.

Comment: that said, I dont understand why the type should be refreshed if the parameter supplied to the type provider have not changed. this should be changed.

Comment: The compiler has no idea if the external world has changed.  Your database connection string may be the same, but the schema of the database itself may have changed.  It is up to the type provider implementation to decide when things change.  As a result, most type providers need a layer of memoizing cache.

Comment: While there are always cases where it is necessary I would at least add a flag to specify this behaviour. If the stability of VS for a common case should be made dependent on an external implementation, at least option should be given to make it conscious and easy to not hurt VS too much.  Given on one hand : the probability that the schema (not the info) might change every half second, and on the other hand the (potentially multiple) impact on the stability of Visual Studio, I think if imagine many type providers being there in the future it makes sense to have a flag.

Comment: Also it is not obvious at all which function get called when (ok there aren't many but still). this is an implementation detail of VS. So it would make sense the API provides a way to deal with the consequence of its own action, like specifying conditions under which the schema is refreshed.